# Matlab multiple connections tcpip

Tags: matlab, tcp, port, fwrite

I have 6 led lights ruled by a matlab program through wifi. I can change smoothly the light spectrum of just one of them using matlab's tcpip command. 
However, if I want to send the desired spectrum to all of them at the same time, I have to use fwrite() ,and other commands, 6 times. It really slows down the process. Moreover, some of them don't react.

I know several ports can be opened in just one sentence.

Is there a way to send information to all the clients connected with just one command?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: I don't have access to them right now, I will post it later, but do u know if there is a way, in matlab, to send data to several connections using fwrite? is there any other way to do that?

Comment: where is your code? please edit the question.